# OAuth 2.0 google plus log in implementation

Tags: android, authentication, webview, google-oauth

I have been searching all over the internet and count find a step by step oauth 2 google plus authentication implementation. Since also I am a beginner to android development some of the tutorials were a bit too much for me. I am using a webview to log in my users to google plus. Can anybody please provide me or redirect me to a detailed step by step implementation of the OAuth 2 in android. Thank you.